# Can't install http module with luarocks on Ubuntu

Tags: lua, luarocks

HTTP module installation is failing on Ubuntu with following error:

```
root@someserver:/var/log# luarocks install http
Warning: falling back to wget - install luasec to get native HTTPS support
Installing https://luarocks.org/http-0.4-0.all.rock
Missing dependencies for http 0.4-0:
   cqueues >= 20161214 (not installed)
   luaossl >= 20161208 (not installed)
   basexx >= 0.2.0 (not installed)
   binaryheap >= 0.3 (not installed)
   fifo (not installed)

http 0.4-0 depends on cqueues >= 20161214 (not installed)
Installing https://luarocks.org/cqueues-20200726.51-0.src.rock

Error: Failed installing dependency: https://luarocks.org/cqueues-20200726.51-0.src.rock - Could not find header file for CRYPTO
  No file openssl/crypto.h in /usr/local/include
  No file openssl/crypto.h in /usr/include
You may have to install CRYPTO in your system and/or pass CRYPTO_DIR or CRYPTO_INCDIR to the luarocks command.
Example: luarocks install cqueues CRYPTO_DIR=/usr/local
```

Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

Seems OpenSSL isn't installed in your system. So try running:

```
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
```